# log4j2 in scala on sbt complie gives Unresolved dependencies path

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, log4j2, intellij-14

**I'm trying to use log4j2 in scala.
Below is my build.sbt**

```
name := "trial"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" %% "log4j-api" % "2.12.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" %% "log4j-core" % "2.12.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" %% "log4j-api-scala" % "2.12.1"
```

**How to resolve these errors:**

[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:

[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api_2.13:2.12.1

sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api_2.13:2.12.1

not found: /Users/username/.ivy2/local/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api_2.13/2.12.1/ivys/ivy.xml

**Note :**

There is no directory /Users/username/.ivy2/local/

but I can see there is /Users/username/.ivy2/cache/

and plugins log4j-api,core,api-scala are present in cache.

**The IDE i'm using is IntelliJ IDEA.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems

- You are using Scala 2.13 however the latest build of [log4j-api-scala](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api-scala) is for Scala 2.12.
- The latest version of log4j-api-scala is `11.0` not `2.12.1`
- [log4j-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api) and [log4j-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core) are Java libraries so we should use single `%` instead of double`%%`